# Adding constraints to a UILabel to put within a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, cashapelayer, programmatically-created

I have a problem where I am trying to center a UILabel within a programmatically generated circle (CAShapeLayer). The problem is that CAShapeLayer is not extended from UIView or NSLayoutGuide, so I am getting a runtime error with the following segment of code:

```
let circlePathLayer = CAShapeLayer()

let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: statusLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: circlePathLayer, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) //Cannot set circlePathLayer
```

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView, or NSLayoutGuide.'

Comment: Basically, CAShapeLayer is not a UIView or NSLayoutGuide. I don't know of any other ways to programmatically set constraints.

Comment: moved the Constraint code from the initWithNib method to viewDidLoad